# firebase last record only

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

I want to append only the last record added to firebase to a table. I tried

```
firebase().database().ref()
  .orderByChild("dateAdded")
  .limitToLast(1)
  .on("child_added", function (snapshot) {
    $('.table').append(
      "<tr><td>" + snapshot.val().train + 
      "</td><td>" + snapshot.val().destination + 
      "</td><td>" + snapshot.val().frequency + 
      "</td></tr>"
    );
  });
```

The first time I add a new entry it works but the second new entry is added twice, third - three times, etc.

Is there a way that will only add each new entry only once?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems you need to read your data only once and not every time data is changed at the specified database reference

So you should do:

```
firebase().database().ref()
  .orderByChild("dateAdded")
  .limitToLast(1)
  .once("child_added....
```

Have a look at the documentation:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once

Comment: Thanks. This worked perfectly!  I tried to up-vote your answer but I am new to coding and don't have enough cred to make the ticker go up.

Comment: @PaulaMacT :-) I think that you should be able to accept the answer (clicking the grey checkmark, which will then become green), see https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer Thanks and welcome to SO.

Comment: @ RenaudTarnec checked :)